# Грамматическая основа:

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, основа

Яниль старался изучать языки, и это ему не раз уже пригодилось.

в 1 части ГО - Яниль старался, а во 2? это пригодилось? или пригодилось? (неполнота одной из частей?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основа первого предложения: ***Яниль старался изучать***. Основа второго предложения: ***это пригодилось***. Здесь указательное местоимение *это* является подлежащим. Получается, оба предложения по структуре двухкомпанентные.

Answer (score 2):

**Яниль старался изучать** языки, и **это** ему не раз уже **пригодилось**.

В первом предложении глагол "старался" имеет модальное значение, поэтому это составное глагольное сказуемое.

Comment: Ой, а вы действительно правы. Как-то не заметил его. Сейчас обновлю вопрос.